# lightbox2 working in Live Preview, but not on server

Tags: lightbox2

I followed the instructions on the lightbox page (https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started) and everything works just as it should in Live Preview of my code editor, Brackets - but when I upload the page to my server, although the modal opens correctly from the thumbnail, I don't get the nav controls (prev and next and close button), or the image caption or numbering ("Image 1 of x") on the bottom left.  Not sure why this would be.  Can anyone assist?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super-embarrassed here to admit my mistake, but I neglected to upload the Lightbox css and js files to my server - which was why the code worked in Live Preview but not on the server.  Duh!  Couldn't see the forest for the trees ...